# How to span partially in the specific css grid area?

Tags: css, grid, css-grid

I am new to CSS grid, I am planning to create the following layout with Grid rather than flex, but I am not able to find a way to use partial grid area. I also tried splitting into 8fr. Is it possible to do it with CSS grid? Fractions may change later on as well. Like instead of 1/3 space in the first row. It might change to 1/4, 1/4, 2/4.

Can someone let me know if it's possible to do it in one grid area or not? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: find something than can be divided by 8 and by 3 = 24

Comment: Taking a simple view, for one grid you've got essentially 24 columns (3 X 8). The top row has 3 8fr items, the middle row has 2 items, the first at 16fr and the second at 8fr and the final row has 8 items each 3fr wide.

Comment: A nice reference for [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)